# Finding the max in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am very new to MIPS, I'm working on an assignment which to find the max between 2 numbers given by user, but I encountered two error that I could not understand why, the code that I wrote started from **max:**. Thank you for your help

error 1: line 35 column 9: "$ra": operand is of incorrect type

error 2: line 40 column 18: "else": operand is of incorrect type

```
.text
 main:
 li   $sp, 0x7ffffffc    # initialize $sp

# PROLOGUE
subu $sp, $sp, 8        # expand stack by 8 bytes
sw   $ra, 8($sp)        # push $ra (ret addr, 4 bytes)
sw   $fp, 4($sp)        # push $fp (4 bytes)
addu $fp, $sp, 8        # set $fp to saved $ra

li   $v0, 5             # read x into a0
syscall
move $a0, $v0

li   $v0, 5             # read y into a1
syscall
move $a1, $v0

# lw  $a1, arg0          # a1 = arg1
# lw    $a2, arg1
jal  max                 # v0 = max(arg0, arg1)

move $a0, $v0           # print_int(rval)
li   $v0, 1
syscall
li   $v0, 11            # print_char(\n)
li   $a0, 10
syscall

# EPILOGUE
move $sp, $fp           # restore $sp
lw   $ra, ($fp)         # restore saved $ra
lw   $fp, -4($sp)       # restore saved $fp
j    $ra                # return to kernel
max:
  #PROLOGUE
 # $a0 = x, $a1 = y
sle $a0, $a1, else  # if(x <= y), jump to else
move $t0, $a0       # if (x > y), x is max
else:   move $t0, $a1       # set $t0 = $t2, y is max
```

Comment: You cannot `j` to a register, there is the `jr` opcode for that.

Comment: `sle` is a mathematical operation, a binary operator, for determining relation -- you cannot give it a label; it has a register target, which you can use in conjunction with a subsequent branch instruction like `bne` or `beq`, which do accept a label.

Answer (score 0):

- `j $ra` needs to be `jr $ra`
- `sle $a0, $a1, else` should be `ble $a0, $a1, else`

That should fix both assembler errors.